# If I receive a new contract from the same employer, can I be furloughed?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, employment

I have been working for a company since July 2019. First it was an 8 week fixed term contract (a paid summer internship). Following immediately from that (excluding a weekend) I was on a zero hours contract, which continues to this day.

In late 2019 I was offered a permanent role with a date to be confirmed (essentially, once I had completed my degree). I signed this (undated, but salary and hours specified) contract, and continued working on the zero hours contract.

Now, I know the end date of my degree, and can give the employer a date at which I can start full time. Currently, I expect them to accept whatever date I propose.

My concern is this: right now I am not furloughed, and it does not look like I will need to be in the future. However, there is a slim chance that could happen. Would starting this new contract exclude me from being furloughed?

I’ve had a look at the [government‘s eligibility page](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/check-if-you-could-be-covered-by-the-coronavirus-job-retention-scheme), but, unsurprisingly it doesn’t mention my specific situation!

So, **after starting a new contract for the same employer, could I be furloughed at a later date?**

Comment: What do you mean by "furloughed"? On leave?

Comment: @Greendrake it’s a legal term due to Coronavirus. On leave, salary paid by government. See the link

Comment: Pending any responses here, the ACAS helpline might be able to help you although in the present circumstances there may be long queues. Call free on 0300 123 1100. https://www.acas.org.uk/contact